# Android tablet stuck at boot screen

Tags: boot-loop

I have a non-branded, non-rooted Chinese tablet with model number X5. It is working fine for a few days. But one day, when I started the tablet, it got stuck on the Android screen. After 10, 20, and even 30 minutes, it remains there and then goes off.

How to fix it?

Comment: More details please. Exact brand name and model would be helpful. What have you tried so far (turning it off and back on? Factory reset?) Has this started happening after you installed a new app?

Comment: It might help to hard-reset it by "poking" something like a needle into the "reset-hole" for a couple of seconds (this is the same as removing the battery, if you could do that).

Answer (score 0):

I am not an expert on the subject, but if you hold down the power key for ten to maybe thirty seconds, you can get them to reboot completely. Mine got stuck on a screen when I first got it. It just stuck on some arbitrary screen but I think that's how I got it to reboot. But I am not sure how long you have to hold down the button, but it is some length of time.

Comment: I have already done this but nothing happened

Answer (score -2):

Press the power key and volume up key to enter recovery mode.
Delete user data and restart the device.