# Nexus S won't turn on HELP!

Tags: applications, rooting, 4.1-jelly-bean, samsung-galaxy-nexus, password

i got issues with my Samsung Galaxy Nexus S i9023. It's new mobile. After 2 months i was msg's with my friends,then my phone just restart and its was fine for 1 min. then it turn off. And when i try to turn it on it's showing NEXUS Logo (https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=lWA6WFi3-RM) like in this video. And its can take hours but its will never turn on. I tried to use bootsettings (http://nexusshacks.com/wp-content/uploads/2011/02/nexus-s-root-6.jpg) recovery. But it wont help at all same way. 
Thanks and answer soon.

Comment: Mine is an I9023XXKI1 - but it's not new. I bought that in Dec 2011. I'm running it with CM11 and it hangs now and then, too. Taking out akku and putting it in again fixes it.

Comment: @ott
Hey,can you be more specific.Taking out akku ? you mean battery? I already tried it and replace it with other.

Comment: Not replacing. Just taking it out, then putting it in again and boot. The classic hard boot like on a desktop.

Comment: @ott-- Did it for like 10 minutes,nothing. My Computer doesent recigonize when i USB it. Can i somehow install a new OS ? And i tried everything in boot menu. Nothing helps.

Comment: Safe Mode or Hard Reset. What about them? Did none of them worked? A Similar question where the screen is stuck at boot logo was asked here - https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/64248/android-tablet-stuck-at-boot-screen

Comment: Hello its worked,one last question my speaker is stopped working.

Answer (score -1):

1. You need the binary image of recovery and ROM
2. Now start in fastboot mode
3. Flash the recovery
4. Then flash the ROM

The recovery and ROM can found on manufacturer's website. However, it is a good idea to try to claim the warranty as it's still 2 months, though I think they will not fix it as you have rooted your device.

Issue the following commands on the terminal:

```
fastboot devices
fastboot flash recovery recovery.img
fastboot flash system rom.img
fastboot flash reboot
```